# NestJs Oauth Client to consume a REST API

Tags: oauth-2.0, nestjs

I'trying to consume an authenticated REST API (Oauth2) from a NestJs application in order to use a third party API without a FrontEnd exposed.

So my goal is to create an OAuth2 Client and consume a 3rd party service exposed in a url saving the token in my server (cache or a variable) in order to so that the app doesn't have to re-login to oauth multiple times.

Any Suggestions? Any sample project to understand the flow?

Thanks in advice